# Google Map API does not provide optimized route even though optimizeWaypoints is set to True

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
var request = {
        origin: "34.040531,-118.255403",
        destination: "34.040531,-118.255403",
        waypoints: [{ location: "48.182379, -117.042542", stopover: true }, 
                    { location: "38.657527,-120.972854", stopover: true }],
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,      
        optimizeWaypoints: true,      
};
```

It gives incorrect path:

```
"34.040531,-118.255403" -> "48.182379, -117.042542" -> "38.657527,-120.972854" -> "34.040531,-118.255403" 
Miles:- 2152 miles
```

[Attached image for incorrect path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnT4y.jpg)!

But optimized route should be

```
"34.040531,-118.255403" -> "38.657527,-120.972854" -> "48.182379, -117.042542"  -> "34.040531,-118.255403"
Miles: 1307 miles
```

---

*How miles are calculated? (As per suggestion i have added this in question*

---

Miles is calculated from Google API response

**Google Gives Long Route (2152)**

A:"34.040531,-118.255403"  #110 E 9th St, Los Angeles, CA
B:"48.182379, -117.042542" #235 N. Union Ave, Newport, WA
C:"38.657527,-120.972854"  #3300 Coach Lane, Cameron Park, CA
A:"34.040531,-118.255403"  #110 E 9th St, Los Angeles, CA

**Optimize route should be (1307)**
A:"34.040531,-118.255403"  #110 E 9th St, Los Angeles, CA 
B:"38.657527,-120.972854"  #3300 Coach Lane, Cameron Park, CA
C:"48.182379, -117.042542" #235 N. Union Ave, Newport, WA 
A:"34.040531,-118.255403"  #110 E 9th St, Los Angeles, CA

Comment: Interesting.  You've said go from point A, via points B and C, back to point A (in other words a round trip through B and C).  Google says A -> B -> C -> A = 2152 miles, but you say A -> C -> B -> A = 1307 miles.  In other words doing the journey in the opposite direction adds 845 miles (making the short version you claim is only 1307 miles 65% longer)!  How are you calculating the distances?

Comment: Anybody who can help me to resolve this issue, seems no reply, should I consider this issue resides in google API

Comment: I repeat - how are you calculating the distances in miles, where do you get 2152 and 1307 from?

Comment: I have explained in new answer as comment box is so basic

Comment: as per suggestion include calculate details in question

Comment: I want to know exactly how you're working out the distances of 2152 and 1307 - is this something Google are giving you, or do you have your own javascript calculating this?  Show us the code you're using to get those distances

Comment: We have created code how we calculate distance please find at https://github.com/ganesha8shiva/SampleGoogleMap/blob/master/Sample-MapAPI.html

Below two lines calculates miles
var route = response.routes[0];
var d = route.legs[i].distance.text;

PS: In demo we have set optimizeWaypoints false however when set that true it will always give unoptimized "2152"

Comment: Example is clear enough to display how we do the calculation, seeking some short of solution for this

Comment: this issue persist in google API, can somebody look into this, waiting for response, all required things are given

Comment: 1307 miles ~= 2103 km.  Is it possibly you're mis-interpreting the results between the two types?  I don't see you specifying either [Imperial or Metric](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#UnitSystem) anywhere

Comment: no we are not mis-interpreting the result, we calculate only in miles and result we get 1307 miles and 2152 miles (not 2103)

Answer (score 2):

So here's what's happening.  You're planning the journey as a round-trip, starting and ending at point A.

If you choose 'optimized' you're going A -> B -> C -> A.

If you choose 'not optimized' you're going A -> C -> B -> A.

The distances between these is as follows:

- A-B = 406 miles
- B-C = 899 miles
- A-C = 1252 miles

Adding those three distances, you get a total of 2557 miles, which is the distance for the total round-trip, regardless of which way round you do the journey, optimized or non-optimized.

You're looping like this in your code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= response.routes[0].legs.length - 2; i++) {
    var route = response.routes[0];
    var d = route.legs[i].distance.text;
    totalmiles = totalmiles + roundNumber(parseFloat((d.split(" ")[0]).replace(",", "")), 2);
    document.getElementById('TotalMiles').innerHTML = totalmiles + " miles";
}
```

Notice you're looping to length-2.  You are travelling between 4 points, therefore you have 3 legs to the journey.  But in calculating the distance you're looping 0..1, and you're deliberately (I assume?) not counting the final leg back to the end destination.

So you're calculating the distances like so:

- optimized = A -> B -> C  = 406 + 899 = 1305
- not optimized = A -> C -> B = 1252 + 899 = 2151

So by not counting the leg back from the penultimate stop to the end destination, that explains  the differences in journey length.

Change your loop to be like this, so you count the final leg of your journey too:

```
for (i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
```

I can't make it any clearer than that.

Comment: You are dead right we missed to calculate last leg to complete round trip, we do necessary changes  so we take either case but eventually end up 2557 miles

Thanks Heaps Duncan

Comment: It took a while but glad you finally got it sorted out